# Slow Running Query on a simple update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have an Templates table which contains templates and a few counters (ie: `sent_count`) for how often the templates are used.

In production, I'm running into some issues where sometimes, updates of `sent_count` are very slow - like 7.5M ms - which I'm assuming means it is stuck forever. As these are happening in background jobs, eventually all of my background sidekiq jobs are eventually stuck on these long running queries, which never timeout since no error is thrown. I'm using Sidekiq which currently doesn't have a job timeout mechanism.

There are only <25k rows in the table. Also when these updates tend to get stuck, it seems they often are all related to a single user's templates. I don't currently have an index on `sent_count` as it is not a foreign key or key of any sort.

Here's my model code for where I update the `sent_count`

```
def increase_sent_count!
  update_attributes!(sent_count: (sent_count + 1)) 
end
```

**Why** is this happening?

**How** can I either add index, restructure my db or code to prevent this from happening?

[image: PG Hero suggests I add an index]
PgHero suggests finds that these queries update queries are my slowest ones, and suggests I add an index. However my understanding was that adding index increases read/lookup speed not write speed.

Comment: UPDATE does a lookup for the row using `where` clause and that will be reduced if you add an index thereby improving the performance

Comment: It could be transactions being held open that are causing the update to be delayed. In which case it wouldn't be the actual update that is taking a long time but that the update is waiting for another transaction to close in which the templates are also being updated. You'd have to prod around a bit to see if that is the case - and I'm obviously not confident enough that it is the problem that I'm posting this as an answer - but it's something to consider.

Comment: Show us the quey plan. And the table definitions, including indexes.